# Separating vuex stores for dynamically created components

Tags: javascript, module, store, vuex, on-the-fly

This was the question got me stuck for a little bit. Unfortunately, I coudn't find answer here (*asking also didn't help*). So after doing some research and asking here and there, it seems that I got the solution to this issue.

> If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you
>   would like to document that knowledge in public so that others
>   (including yourself) can find it later.

Of course, my answer may not be the ideal one, moreover I know it is not, that's the key point why I'm posting - to improve it.

Note, I'm not using actions in example. The idea is the same.

Let's begin with **stating the problem:**

Imagine we have `App.vue` which dynamically generates its local component named `Hello`.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>
      <hello v-for="i in jobs" :key="i" :id="i"></hello>
      <button @click="addJob">New</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>   

<script>
import Hello from './components/Hello'

export default {
  components: {
    Hello
  }...
```

**`store.js`**

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    jobs: []
  }
})
```

We are using `v-for` directive to generate components by iterating through an array `jobs`. Our `store` as of now consists of only `state` with an empty array.
Button `New` should do 2 things:

**1)** create new component `Hello`, in other words add element to `jobs` (let it be numbers), which are going to be assigned as `key` and `id` of `<hello>`, and passed to local component as `props`.

**2)** generate local stores - **modules** - to keep any data scoped to newly created components.

**`Hello.vue`**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="number" :value="count">
    <button @click="updateCountPlus">+1</button>
  </div>
</template>

export default {
  props: ['id']
}
```

Simple component - input with a button adding 1.

Our goal is to design something like this:
[image: Vuex local stores]

Comment: Great question and great diagram!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For the first operation of `NEW` button - **generating components** - we add `mutation` to our `store.js`

```
 mutations: {
    addJob (state) {
      state.jobs.push(state.jobs.length + 1)
...
}
```

Second, **creating local modules**. Here we're going to use `reusableModule` to generated multiple instances of a module. That module we keep in separate file for convinience. Also, *note use of function for declaring module state*.

```
const state = () => {
  return {
    count: 0
  }
}

const getters = {
  count: (state) => state.count
}

const mutations = {
  updateCountPlus (state) {
    state.count++
  }
}

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  mutations
}
```

To use `reusableModule` we import it and apply dynamic module registration.

**`store.js`**

```
import module from './reusableModule'

const {state: stateModule, getters, mutations} = module

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    jobs: []
  },
  mutations: {
    addJob (state) {
      state.jobs.push(state.jobs.length + 1)
      store.registerModule(`module${state.jobs.length}`, {
        state: stateModule,
        getters,
        mutations,
        namespaced: true // making our module reusable
      })
    }
  }
})
```

After, we're going to link `Hello.vue` with its storage. We may need `state`, `getters`, `mutations`, `actions` from `vuex`. To access storage we need to create our `getters`. Same with `mutations`.

**`Home.vue`**

```
<script>

export default {
  props: ['id'],
  computed: {
     count () {
        return this.$store.getters[`module${this.id}/count`]
     }
  },
  methods: {
    updateCountPlus () {
        this.$store.commit(`module${this.id}/updateCountPlus`)
     } 
  }
}
</script>
```

Imagine we have lots of `getters`, `mutations` and `actions`. Why not use `{mapGetters}` or `{mapMutations}`? When we have several modules and we know the path to module needed, we can do it. Unfortunately, we do not have access to module name.

> The code is run when the component's module is executed (when your app
>   is booting), not when the component is created. So these helpers can
>   only be used if you know the module name ahead of time.

There is little help here. We can separate our `getters` and `mutations` and then import them as an object and keep it clean.

```
<script>
import computed from '../store/moduleGetters'
import methods from '../store/moduleMutations'

export default {
  props: ['id'],
  computed,
  methods
}
</script>
```

Returning to `App` component. We have to commit our `mutation` and also let's create some `getter` for `App`. To show how can we access data located into modules.

**`store.js`**

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    jobs: []
  },
  getters: {
    jobs: state => state.jobs,
    sumAll (state, getters) {
      let s = 0
      for (let i = 1; i <= state.jobs.length; i++) {
        s += getters[`module${i}/count`]
      }
      return s
    }
  } 
...
```

Finishing code in `App` component

```
<script>
import Hello from './components/Hello'
import {mapMutations, mapGetters} from 'vuex'

    export default {
      components: {
        Hello
      },
      computed: {
        ...mapGetters([
          'jobs',
          'sumAll'
        ])
      },
      methods: {
        ...mapMutations([
          'addJob'
        ])
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: You could take this pattern, and further simplify it by using a wrapper such as [vuex-stores](https://github.com/ElMassimo/vuex-stores#dynamic-stores-factory-)

Answer (score 2):

Hi and thank you for posting your question and your solution.

I started learning Vuex couple days ago and came across a similar problem. I've checked your solution and came up with mine which doesn't require registering new modules. I find it to be quite an overkill and to be honest I don't understand why you do it. There is always a possibility I've misunderstood the problem.

I've created a copy of your markup with a few differences for clarity and demonstration purposes.

I've got:

1. JobList.vue - main custom component
2. Job.vue - job-list child custom component
3. jobs.js - vuex store module file

JobList.vue (which is responsible for wrapping the job(s) list items)

```
<template>
    <div>
        <job v-for="(job, index) in jobs" :data="job" :key="job.id"></job>

        <h3>Create New Job</h3>
        <form @submit.prevent="addJob">
            <input type="text" v-model="newJobName" required>
            <button type="submit">Add Job</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import store from '../store/index'
    import job from './job';

    export default {
        components: { job },
        data() {
            return {
                newJobName: ''
            };
        },
        computed: {
            jobs() {
                return store.state.jobs.jobs;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            addJob() {
                store.dispatch('newJob', this.newJobName);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The Job

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h5>Id: {{ data.id }}</h5>
        <h4>{{ data.name }}</h4>
        <p>{{ data.active}}</p>
        <button type="button" @click="toggleJobState">Toggle</button>
        <hr>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    import store from '../store/index'

    export default {
        props: ['data'],
        methods: {
            toggleJobState() {
                store.dispatch('toggleJobState', this.data.id);
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

And finally the jobs.js Vuex module file:

```
export default {
    state: {
        jobs: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'light',
                active: false
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'medium',
                active: false
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'heavy',
                active: false
            }
        ]
    },

    actions: { //methods
        newJob(context, jobName) {
            context.state.jobs.push({
                id: context.getters.newJobId,
                name: jobName,
                active: false
            });
        },
        toggleJobState(context, id) {
            context.state.jobs.forEach((job) => {
                if(job.id === id) { job.active = !job.active; }
            })
        }
    },

    getters: { //computed properties
        newJobId(state) { return state.jobs.length + 1; }
    }
}
```

It's possible to add new jobs to the store and as the "active" property suggest, you can control every single individual job without the need for a new custom vuex module.

Comment: This is all fine in your case. In your toggleJobState, you find the specific items from your jobs array and mutate that data with a loop and some logic. Thats the essence of your answer. It doesn't quite answer the quiestion though imo.
What if the job components had a form which relied on - lets say jobNameForm state - for actively inputing name. Altering name in one job would alter the names in all jobs if model bound. Submitting a form with an action and mutations would have the the same impact on all jobs. Right? Look at his diagram. He wants 3 local instances of a state. You have 1.