# vuex unknown mutation type in registered module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, state, vuex

i just wanna create dynamic registered module in vuex, but it seems doesnt work.
this is my store file

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import descriptionModule from './module/descriptionModule';
const {state: stateModule, getters, mutations} = descriptionModule;

const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      descriptions: [],
    },
    mutations: {
      addDescriptions(state, payload){
        state.descriptions.push(state.descriptions.length + 1);
        createStore().registerModule(`descriptionModule${payload}`, {
          state: stateModule,
          getters,
          mutations,
          namespaced: true // making our module reusable
        });
      }
    }
  })
};

export default createStore
```

and this is my custom module that i will registered

```
const state = () => {
  return {description: ''}
};
const getters = {
  description: (state) => state.description
};
const mutations = {
  updateDescription(state, payloads){
    state.description = payloads;
  }
};
export default {
  state,getters,mutations
}
```

and then this is my custom methods that will call addDescriptions mutation and commit updateDescription from registeredModule

```
beforeMount(){
  console.log("hahahaha");
  this.$store.commit('addDescriptions', this.id);
},
... more code ....
methods: {
      onType(editor, content){
        console.log(this.$store.state.a);
        console.log(this.$store.state);
        console.log(this.$store);
        this.$store.commit(`descriptionModule${this.id}/updateDescription`, content, {root: true})
      }
    }
```

every `onType` called, i get an error `unknown mutation type: descriptionModuleeditor1/updateDescription` in browser.

currently iam following this solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44345704/separating-vuex-stores-for-dynamically-created-components) , but it doesnt work for me :(

can anyone solve this,,, sorry for bad english

Answer (score 6, accepted):

invoke `$store.registerModule()` via component/pages on `beforeMount()`:

```
beforeMount(){
      this.$store.registerModule(`descriptionModule${this.id}`, {
        state: stateModule,
        getters,
        mutations,
        namespaced: true // making our module reusable
      });
    },
```